# flask-sqlalchemy three way association

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have three sqlalchemy tables as follows. Categories-feeds is a many-many relationship, and feeds-articles is a one-many relationship.

What I would like to do is be able to access the articles of a category's feeds by querying the Category object. Something like:

```
Category.query.get(1).articles
```

How can I make that work the following code?

```
category_feeds = db.Table('category_feeds',
    db.Column('feed_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('feed.id')),
    db.Column('category_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
)

class Article(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.Text)
    content = db.Column(db.Text)
    href = db.Column(db.Text)
    feed_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('feed.id'))

class Feed(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.Text)
    xml_url = db.Column(db.Text)
    html_url = db.Column(db.Text)
    articles = db.relationship('Article', backref='feed')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(self, key, value)

class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.Text)
    feeds = db.relationship('Feed', secondary=category_feeds,
        backref=db.backref('categories'))
    articles = ???

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a property on the `Category` class which would run the query you need:

```
class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.Text)
    feeds = db.relationship('Feed', secondary=category_feeds,
        backref=db.backref('categories'))

    @property
    def articles(self):
        this_category = Category.query.get(self.id)
        articles = db.session.query(Article).join(Article.feed).filter(Feed.categories.contains(this_category))
        return articles

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

With that, you could simply:

```
articles = Category.get(1).articles
print [x.title for x in articles]
```